# writing generic filter using grep in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way i can write the following piece of code to be more generic?

```
var result = $.grep(myObjectArray, function(e){ 

    return e.Prop1 == 'SomeVal';

});
```

This is what i want to do.

A generic function that will accept `myObjectArray` (Object Array to filter), `Prop1`(Property name) and `SomeVal` (Value to filter) as an argument.

The problem i am facing is that i dont know how will i find the PropertyName in the object as it can be anything.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filterObjectArray(myObjectArray, prop1, someVal) {
    return $.grep(myObjectArray, function (e) {
        return e[prop1] === someVal;
    };
}
```

Note the use of the square bracket syntax for object property access.

Answer (score 1):

To get the property from an object, just use

```
myObject[Prop1]
```

To determine whether an object has a property, use

```
myObject.hasOwnProperty(Prop1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be generic like this?

```
function filterArray(inputArray,customFunction){
 return $.grep(inputArray, function(e){       return customFunction(e);  });
}
```

where `customFunction` can be a user defined function to qualify the object as selected

Example :

```
var sampleArray = [{name:"Ahamed",age: 21}, 
                   {name:"AhamedX",age: 21}, 
                   {name:"Babu",age: 25}, 
                  {name:"Mustafa",age: 27} ];

function nameComparator(obj){
       return obj["name"]=="Ahamed";
}

function ageFilter(obj){
    return obj["age"]>=25;
 }


var filteredArray=filterArray(sampleArray,nameComparator);
alert(filteredArray.length);
var filteredArray=filterArray(sampleArray,ageFilter);
alert(filteredArray.length);
```

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/MAq6c/